# Anchor for Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox-addon, installation

I have a Firefox addon available for my website. I add the download link of the addon to a simple , but when an user click it, it prompts him to download the .XPI file of the addon - Is there any way so I can pop-up the normal EXTENSION INSTALL window for my addon? Is there any special thing to do that or this is available only in addons.mozilla.org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [InstallTrigger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPInstall_API_Reference/InstallTrigger_Object) object. Also, you should be using `application/x-xpinstall` MIME type for your extension file, this will trigger installation even if `InstallTrigger` isn't used (e.g. JavaScript disabled).

Comment: The link you provided doesn't seem to exist!

Comment: @Dugi: It works fine for me but I changed the link (the previous link was using old format, MDN redirected to the new page automatically). You can also check out [InstallTrigger.install()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPInstall_API_Reference/InstallTrigger_Object/Methods/install) method directly.